# Trouble understanding differential equations in Quantum Mechanics.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

*This is my first question on this forum, so I apologize if I am not very clear.*

We have this exercise about three-dimensional harmonic oscillators and there's this differential equation I simply don't understand.
It's $$\frac{d^2u}{d \rho^2} \approx u\rho^2\rho_0^2$$ and the general solution should be $$u(\rho)\approx Ae^{-\frac{\rho_0\rho^2}{2}}+Be^{\frac{\rho_0\rho^2}{2}}$$

Does anyone understand this, and if so could they explain it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a second order differential equation. [Paul's Online Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/introsecondorder.aspx) gives a good introduction to them.

Comment: Are you sure? If $u=\exp(\rho_0\rho^2/2)$ then $u^\prime=\rho_0\rho u$ so $u^{\prime\prime}=(\rho^2\rho_0^2\color{red}{+\rho_0})u$. Incidentally, denoting by $\rho_0$ a constant with the same dimension as $\rho^{-2}$ is very unhelpful. Anyway, I'd recommend consulting [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Example:_3D_isotropic_harmonic_oscillator).

Comment: Yes im pretty sure this is the solution since it was given by the professor and the solution were already reviewed, but thank you very much for the links, this is really helpful !!

Comment: Do you understand the following differential equation?
$$y'' = ax^2y$$